# Code wrapping empty space in class tags

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have the following code in my functions.php which wraps the text in my Wordpress posts in `<class="row">` and `<class ="col-md-10">` and leaves the images intact/unwrapped

functions.php

```
function sr_wrap_content_in_div( $content )
{
$contents = explode("<img", $content);
foreach($contents as $content)
{
    $before_tag = strstr($content, '/>', true); 
    $after_tag = strstr($content, '/>');
    if( $before_tag == '' && $after_tag == '' )
    {
        echo '<div class="content-wrap row"><div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">'; // change it later if you need to
        echo $content;
        echo '</div></div>';
    } else if( $after_tag == '/> ' )
    {
        echo '<img';
        echo $before_tag;
        echo '/>';
    } else 
    {
        echo '<img';
        echo $before_tag;
        echo '/>';
        echo '<div class="content-wrap row"><div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">'; // change here too.
        echo substr($after_tag, 2);
        echo '</div></div>';
    }
}
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'sr_wrap_content_in_div' );
```

The code works, however it wraps empty spaces (in between images, etc) in those classes. This means I cannot apply margin css to `.content-wrap` because it will create gaps in empty spaces.

EDIT :

example output (with issue)

```
<div class="content-wrap row">
   <div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">
      <p>content ... </p>
   </div>
</div>
<img></img>
<div class="content-wrap row">
   <div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">
   </div>
</div>
<img></img>

 etc
```

Comment: No idea what is your problem is

Comment: Problem is it wraps empty spaces (where there is no text) with the row class tags

Comment: Can you place below code to function.php and check 

remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );

Answer (score 1):

To remove empty space could you please try using below code instead of above shared.

```
function sr_wrap_content_in_div( $content ) {
        $contents = explode("<img", $content);

        foreach($contents as $content) {
            $before_tag = strstr($content, '/>', true); 
            $after_tag = strstr($content, '/>');
            if( $before_tag == '' && $after_tag == '' ) {
                echo '<div class="content-wrap row"><div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">' . $content . '</div></div>'; // change it later if you need to
            } else if( $after_tag == '/> ' ) {
                echo '<img' . $before_tag . '/>';
            } else {
                echo '<img' . $before_tag . '/>' . '<div class="content-wrap row"><div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">' . substr($after_tag, 2) . '</div></div>'; // change here too.
            }
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'sr_wrap_content_in_div' );
```

Comment: Tried it but has the same issue. Seems to be when with the images. In the content when two images are after one another, It puts a <div class="row"> ... in between them

Comment: Could you please share me the page URL from your site where it is not displaying correctly so that i can troubleshoot it?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm running it on my localhost as it's in development stage

Comment: Then could you please share the screenshot of it?

Comment: Hi did your tried this in your function.php

remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );

Comment: where in functions does that need to go (before/after)

Comment: Any where, for the time being place it before the function which you given in this question

Comment: I ask as it doesn't solve the issue, wasn't sure if location was important

Comment: Ok then please try to add priority and check 

 remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop',9 );

Comment: Still no change, I am thinking it's somewhere in the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143842/discussion-between-ashkar-and-user3550879).